# Add 30 days to the existing datetime column MYSQL Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

Hi guys I'm trying to update the date on the database in python with mysql.connector but the UPDATE STATEMENT has no effect on column. This is my try code:

```
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**self.db)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = "UPDATE LICENSE_STATUS SET expired_date = (select date_add(expired_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) WHERE user_id = %s"
    cur.execute(query, (user_id,))
    conn.commit()
```

I tried the same query with mysql-workbench and it works

I tried also this query:

```
query = "UPDATE LICENSE_STATUS SET expired_date = date_add(expired_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE user_id = %s"
```

Comment: `UPDATE license_status SET expired_date = expired_date + INTERVAL 30 DAY WHERE user_id = %s`. And look for (error?) messages returned from MySQL server.

Comment: I have not found any errors, the query has no effect

Comment: A have said "messages". ANY!!! "error" was a prediction, and I'm glad that it didn't work out. PS. MySQL can NOT return nothing.